# username will be null when page is refreshed in angular6

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular6

in my `Dasboard Component` i Need to Give a `username` and Send it 
Form Server for Get Detail of User like `fName , lName , Image , . . .`

I Pass the `username` with this way :

when user is loggedin i u get the `username` from `LocalStorage` :

**Login Component :**

```
private usenameSource = new BehaviorSubject<string>('');
userName$ = this.usenameSource.asObservable();

getDecodedAccessToken(): any {
  return jwt_decode(this.getRawAuthToken(AuthTokenType.AccessToken));
}

getUserNameDecode():any {
  const decode = this.getDecodedAccessToken();
  let userName = decode["http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name"];
  return this.usenameSource.next(userName);
}
```

**Dashboard Component :**

```
this.loginService.userName$.subscribe((data) => {
  this.userName = data;
})
```

Now, the problem is that when the browser is refreshing, the username will be null and I need to login again.

whats the problem ? how can i solve this problem ?

Comment: store the name is local storage and then use it from there

Comment: if you have `username` stored in the `local storage` (I aasume under `username` key), then try initialize your `behaviorSubject` with it: `private usenameSource = new BehaviorSubject<string>(localStorage && localStorage.username || '');`

Comment: @Andriy i can access `username` wit hthis : `userName=decode["http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name"];`

Comment: Why you are not using browser's localStorage??

Comment: it also looks like `decode["http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name"]` is asynchronous function, but the you return its result in a synchronous way. You should recheck it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the page refreshes, the "usenameSource" value will be cleared. To keep it, call your method "getUserNameDecode()" again in your service constructor.

```
constructor(...) {
    this.getUserNameDecode();
}

getUserNameDecode():any {
   const decode = this.getDecodedAccessToken();

   if(!decode) {
      // login failed
      return;
   }

   let userName = decode["http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name"];
   return this.usenameSource.next(userName);
}
```

....

Answer (score 1):

I assume that Login Component will be loaded first when you start your application.
And also I assume that you are storing the userName details in local storage as soon as user logs in successfully.
So with that, we must check the userName in local storage first and based on that we must do the further operation.

### Login Component

```
ngOnInit() {
  const status = this.checkUserNameInLocalStorage();
  if (status) {
    this.userName = JSON.parse(window.localStorage['userName']);
  } else {
    // write your logic to get the userName details
  }
}

checkUserNameInLocalStorage() {
  if (window.localStorage['userName']) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Hope this will help you.